# React-Native Router-Flux hide text for an User Role

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a problem about a text in Router-Flux.

I have a page **App.js** in which I put all the routes of the App. 
There I have insert the text "Logout" for the **homepageUtente.js** .

This is the **App.js** page

```
export default class App extends Component {
  static redirectLogout() {
    Alert.alert("Logout", "Logout effettuato con successo");
    Actions.authentication();
  }
  static logout() {
    Utente.clearUtenteLoggato();
    App.redirectLogout();
  }

  // This method that I tried not work.
  static checkUser() {
    Utente.getUtenteLoggato();
    const Roles = global.utente.data.Roles
    return Roles
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root">
          <Scene
            key="authentication"
            component={Authentication}
            navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#64c7c0" }}
            type="reset"
          />

          <Scene
            key="homepageutente"
            component={HomepageUtente}
            type="reset"
            leftTitle="Home"
            leftButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
            onLeft={() => Actions.authentication()}
            rightButtonTextStyle={{ color: "#ffffff" }}

            rightTitle={App.checkUser !== "ROLE_PLUS" ? "Logout" : ""}
            onRight={App.checkUser !== "ROLE_PLUS" ? () => App.logout() : () => {}}

             // This is the way to get out (but obviously it does not distinguish between roles)
            //rightTitle="Logout"
            //onRight={() => App.logout()}
            navigationBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#64c7c0" }}
          />
```

This is the **HomepageUser.js**

```
class HomepageUser extends Component {
   constructor(props){
       super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const FirstName = global.utente.data.Person.FirstName;
        const LastName = global.utente.data.Person.LastName;
        const Roles = global.utente.data.Roles
        console.log(Roles) 
        return (

           <View>

                 <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20,}}>{"Welcome"}</Text>
                 <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 20, color: '#64c7c0', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{FirstName} {LastName}</Text>
                 <Text>{Roles}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

While this is the function that I used for the UserLoggedIn

```
static async getUtenteLoggato() {
    try {
      return await AsyncStorage.getItem("@UtenteLoggato");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

What I should do is that if the user is a user with the role: "ROLE_PLUS" he can't logout. But I don't understand how can I hide the text for this role.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any solution to pass a variable from others to Router Page. It seems a simple way(not the best one) is to define two Scene tag

Authentication page :

```
LoginProcess() {
    //LoginProcess
    var pass = true; //User is authenticated
    if (pass) {
        ToastAndroid.show('clicked!', ToastAndroid.SHORT)
        Actions.homepageutente();
    } else {
        Actions.homepageutente2();
    }
}
```

And in Router:

```
 <Router>
        <Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
            <Scene key="auth">
                <Scene key="login"
                    component={Authentication}
                    title="Please Login"
                    initial
                />
            </Scene>

            <Scene key="homepageutente" hideNavBar ={false}
                component={HomepageUtente}
            title="home page"
                rightTitle={"Log Out"}
            onRight={() => Actions.auth()}
            />
            <Scene key="homepageutente2" hideNavBar ={false}
                component={HomepageUtente}
                title="home page"
            />

        </Scene>
    </Router>
```

Comment: Yes I also had thought to do in this way.. but I need to use only one homepage :(